# Flask's SocketIO isn't sending the right script to my client

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I get this warning in Firefox Developer Tools:

```
The script from “https://js-game-tanks.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“application/octet-stream”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
```

and these errors:

`SyntaxError: illegal character` `socket.io.js:1`

`ReferenceError: io is not defined` `test:10:20`

My thinking is that I should be getting javascript not an octet-stream correct?

My HTML's JavaScript:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   var socket = io();
   socket.on('any event', function(msg) {
         console.log(msg);
   });
</script>
```

Line 10 specifically is `var socket = io();`.

My Python will detect a connection with:

```
@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('\n\nClient connected\n\n')
    emit('we connected',  {'data':'woot woot'})
```

and it will print `client connected` when I load my page.

And for context, this is deployed via Heroku and I'm using Gunicorn.

How do I resolve this? I am new to Socket.IO, so maybe I am just going about this all wrong.

Comment: This problem does not appear to be related to the Socket.IO server in any way. You seem to have issues serving the socket.io client javascript file. Try switching to a CDN hosted client to see if that helps.

Comment: Do you mean to stop using Heroku? Would you have some suggestions that have a free tier? This is just a hobby project.

Comment: No, I mean that you use a CDN in your `<script>` tag, instead of hosting the socket.io.js file yourself. Like this one: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/socket.io.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work, now I have some new problems to address lol.